# Why the identity $ a^x = a^y \Longrightarrow x=y $ do not work for $a<0$?

Tags: exponentiation

All books that i am reading are telling that the identiy $  a^x = a^y \Longrightarrow x=y   ; \,\,\,\,\, a \in \mathbb{R} - \{0,1\} $ $ \,\,\,\,$ also do not work for $a<0$, but, for example, if $ (-2)^2 = (-2)^x  $, than for sure $x=2$.

Than, the identity works for  $a<0$, correct?

Comment: We have $$a^{x-y}=1$$ if $a$ is real, either $a=1$ or $a=-1,x-y$ is even

Comment: what if $x$ is complex?

Comment: The expression $a^x$ all on its own becomes probelmatic when $a < 0$!

Comment: The "identity" doesn't even work for $a=1 > 0$

Comment: @AlexR For $a = 1$ i know it will not, but for $a>0$ it will, correct?

Comment: $a>0$ includes $a=1$, but with this exception it's still only correct for $x,y\in\mathbb R$

Answer (score 3):

It does not work for $a\lt 0$.

If 
$$(-1)^x=(-1)^2,$$
then $x=4$ is another solution.

In general, 
$$(-1)^x=(-1)^2\Rightarrow x=2m (m\in\mathbb Z)$$

Comment: Ok, but if $a<0$ and $a \neq -1$, than it works, correct?

Comment: @Voyager Did you read Hurkyl's comment?

Comment: @mathlove The same objection applies to $a\gt0$.

Comment: @Voyager: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a^b := \exp(b \ln a)$ and even the definition of $\ln a$ is problematic for arbitrary $a\in\mathbb C$ and the complex exponential isn't bijective (unlike the real).
The principal branch of the natural logarithm is not defined for $a\in\mathbb R_-\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: The principal branch of $\ln$ **is** defined for $a < 0$, it is $\ln|a| + i\pi$, but it is not continous across the branch cut.

Comment: @gammatester this is a matter of convention. If you leave it undefined, it is analytic on its domain; if you do define it, it's no longer analytic, making things a lot harder.